# Installing FreeRDP and hit to error: field ‘des3_ctx’ has incomplete type

Tags: linux, ubuntu, remote-desktop, make, c

I was trying to install FreeRDP server using the link : https://github.com/FreeRDP/Remmina/wiki/Compile-on-Ubuntu-16.04

I hit to the below error during

> `make && sudo make install`

```
[ 25%] Building C object libfreerdp-codec/CMakeFiles/freerdp-codec.dir/nsc.c.o
[ 26%] Building C object libfreerdp-codec/CMakeFiles/freerdp-codec.dir/rfx_sse2.c.o
[ 26%] Linking C shared library libfreerdp-codec.so
[ 26%] Built target freerdp-codec
Scanning dependencies of target freerdp-core
[ 27%] Building C object libfreerdp-core/CMakeFiles/freerdp-core.dir/activation.c.o
In file included from /home/hari/openuds/freerdp/FreeRDP-1.0.2/libfreerdp-core/tls.h:23:0,
                 from /home/hari/openuds/freerdp/FreeRDP-1.0.2/libfreerdp-core/transport.h:33,
                 from /home/hari/openuds/freerdp/FreeRDP-1.0.2/libfreerdp-core/mcs.h:24,
                 from /home/hari/openuds/freerdp/FreeRDP-1.0.2/libfreerdp-core/rdp.h:23,
                 from /home/hari/openuds/freerdp/FreeRDP-1.0.2/libfreerdp-core/activation.h:23,
                 from /home/hari/openuds/freerdp/FreeRDP-1.0.2/libfreerdp-core/activation.c:20:
/home/hari/openuds/freerdp/FreeRDP-1.0.2/libfreerdp-core/crypto.h:67:17: error: field ‘des3_ctx’ has incomplete type
  EVP_CIPHER_CTX des3_ctx;
                 ^~~~~~~~
/home/hari/openuds/freerdp/FreeRDP-1.0.2/libfreerdp-core/crypto.h:72:11: error: field ‘hmac_ctx’ has incomplete type
  HMAC_CTX hmac_ctx;
           ^~~~~~~~
libfreerdp-core/CMakeFiles/freerdp-core.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'libfreerdp-core/CMakeFiles/freerdp-core.dir/activation.c.o' failed
make[2]: *** [libfreerdp-core/CMakeFiles/freerdp-core.dir/activation.c.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:494: recipe for target 'libfreerdp-core/CMakeFiles/freerdp-core.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [libfreerdp-core/CMakeFiles/freerdp-core.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:151: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Could you please help me to resolve this issue?

Thanks,
Harry

Comment: I assume that you mean `make && make install`.   Yes, `&` and `&&` mean "and", but please, when you're quoting a command, **quote the command**.

Comment: @Scott I updated the comment, could you help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: I'm a programmer, and if I had this problem, I'd look at the source code (the `.c` and `.h` files, whose names are given, along with line numbers), but that's probably a bad way to do it.  I don't know anything about FreeRDP; you'll get a better answer from somebody who does.    P.S. I hope you're not in a big hurry.  [SU] has users all around the world, in many different time zones, so many of our users are asleep now, or otherwise engaged in activities that prevent them from answering questions on [SE].  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) … Also, Thanksgiving is dawning in the US, so lots of the Americans will be offline for the next 32 hours or so.  If you haven't gotten an answer after two days, I suggest that you click on "flag" and ask to have the question migrated to Unix&Linux.  I notice that they have a "freerdp" tag (although it's not very heavily used), so there might be some FreeRDP experts in that community.